# Ruby on Rails filtering page result by multiple params and save parameters to the next page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Basically I have 4 controllers: one with products, one with categories for this products, one for managing cities, and one for distributing data to the front end (contains static pages, main logic is filtrating showing results).

For now I have the aim to filter my products by city and by category in the same time. I've done basic solution with passing params to url and processing them in my controller.

```
/main/home.html.erb/
<%- City.all.each do |city|%>
    <%= link_to city.name, url_for(category: params[:category], city: city.name)%>
<% end %>

<% Category.all.each do |category| %>
<%= link_to category.name, root_path(category: category.name, city: params[:city]) %>
```

And in the Main controller I have something like for Home action:

```
def home
  @city = City.all
  @offers = Offer.all
  @category = Category.all

  if !params[:city].blank? 
    @city_id = City.find_by(name: params[:city]).id
    @offers = Offer.where(city_id: @city_id).where(category_id: @category_id).order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 4)
  end

  if !params[:category].blank?
    @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
    @offers = Offer.where(category_id: @category_id).where(city_id: @city_id).order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 4)
  end 
end
```

That's make filtering, but after I got redirected to another page, I have to pick up my city again. How to save it for the session?
And may be there is more proper solution to handle this task?
What should I do to get this thing work ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `session`.

```
  if !params[:city].blank?
    session[:current_city] = params[:city] 
    @city_id = City.find_by(name: params[:city]).id
    @offers = Offer.where(city_id: @city_id).where(category_id: @category_id).order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 4)
  end

  if !params[:category].blank?
    session[:current_category] = params[:category]
    @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
    @offers = Offer.where(category_id: @category_id).where(city_id: @city_id).order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 4)
  end
```

Then in the next controllers:

```
params[:city] = session[:current_city] unless params[:city].present?
params[:category] = session[:current_category] unless params[:city].present?
```

After that you can use the params[:city], params[:category] the same way

Comment: Hey, that worked! Tried sessions before, but was catched by small syntax mistakes, as I see now. Thank you.

PS: For those who will perform this task, further i replaced params in all GET requests with session variable. + I replaced my 'city selection' to main layout, that force me to update my selection such as :
<%= link_to city.name, url_for(city: city.name), :current_city => params[:city], :action => 'home'%> . Hope this will help to someone else, 'cause it took me quite big time to handle.